# Strictly increasing function on positive integers giving value between $100$ and $200$

Tags: functions

I'm looking for some sort of function $f$ that can take any integer $n>0$ and give a real number $100 \le m \lt 200$ such that if $a \lt b$ then $f(a) \lt f(b)$. How can I do that? I'm a programmer and I need this for an application of mine.

Comment: Is $m$ a real number or an integer?

Comment: m is real number

Comment: Is $n$ an integer or a real number?

Comment: i mentioned that the formula can take any number from (1,2,3,...) so i think it's obvious that it's an integer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try
$$f(x)= 150 + 50 \cdot \frac{x}{1+|x|}$$
This is a bijection from $\mathbb{R}$ to $(100,200)$.
The graph is
[image]

which gives you the idea why it is monotone and why it works.

Comment: thanks for the help i appreciate it

Comment: your answer wasn't exactly what i was looking for but i modified it to this $$f(x)= 200 \cdot \frac{x}{1+|x|}$$

Comment: That will be fine for natural numbers.

Comment: @RachidO.: Note that your modified function doesn't do the trick for all reals, but only for reals $\ge1.$

Comment: @RachidO.  Notice that for this domain that's the same as $200 - 200/(1+x)$, which makes the increasing property more obvious.  Perhaps a slightly simpler function would be $200 - 100/x$.

Comment: @ErickWong yes you are right and your solution is nice too and more simple :)

Answer (score 2):

$\tan\dfrac{\pi (x-150) }{100 } $ is a monotone bijection from $(100,200)$ to $\mathbb{R}$. (You can obtain it by looking at $\tan x$ and then trying a linear function). The inverse of this is the function you want.

Answer (score 2):

$f(n)=200-2^{-n}$ satisfies your criteria.